# how docker executes windows container?

Tags: linux, docker

1. As i understand, docker use linux VM even i install it on windows OS.
   So i agree that windows docker can execute linux container.
   But then, how windows docker executes windows container?
2. Can i make container with other OS?
   In other words, can i make container(having windows & windows app) and run it on linux docker?
   As i know, docker does not support other OS in image, but it looks like some people is saying it is possible that make windows container and run it on linux.
   Docker container shares just one kernel, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1. That first statement is incorrect. Docker uses the underlying OS feature (container) to run its stack/daemon. The OS is responsible for instantiating the container itself. That means a Linux OS will instantiate a Linux container and Windows host will instantiate a Windows container. So, if you install Docker on Windows you don't have a Linux VM. Instead, you have the ability to instantiate Windows containers directly without the need to run Linux at all. To answer the question itself: The process is pretty much the same as Linux. You pull images with `docker pull` and then run them with `docker run`. You can also build images with `docker build` and everything else.
2. Windows containers can only run on Windows hosts (either Windows 10/11 or Windows Server). For Linux containers, that's not so strict. You can run Linux containers on Windows for development purposes, by leveraging the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

There's much more details on these on the Microsoft documentation page: https://cda.ms/4nN

Comment: Thanks for reply. But as i know, docker uses linux's container feature. So even we install docker on windows OS, docker make linux VM and run containers on that VM. Is it incorrect? Then, windows also support container feature by it self without linux VM?

Comment: As i understand https://cda.ms/4nN, windows also support container feature by it self without support of linux VM. So if it is windows container, windows OS will handle it by windows's container feature. If it is linux container, windows OS will hanle it by WSL. So 
container can't have OS, all containers will be run in same host OS. Is it right understan?

Comment: To clarify: You always use a OS for the container, it's just that its kernel is shared with the container host - that is the reason Linux containers work on Linux and Windows containers on Windows. Your comment on WSL is correct and to further explain, WSL is nothing more than a VM running on Windows, which goes back to my point earlier that  the container shares the host OS kernel.